# Send information to COM port from MVC.NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, serial-port

Is there any way to send information from my C# MVC.NET application (that is on a server computer inside a local network) to another PC (in the same network) which has a (fiscal) printer connected in a Serial Port?

My webapp is working ok, and I have a winform app that works ok too. But I cannot connect them.
So I think in sen all the information directly from the web app to the specific IP and COM port.

Is that possible in c#?

Comment: you'd have to write a program that accepts incoming IP connections and then sends the data out the serial port.

Comment: But I need a web service for that? or if it possible to do a Winform or a Console app that waits for the information?

Because the idea is that it connect dynamically to the computer that contains has a printer just knowing the IP

Answer (score 0):

Physical hardware are not accessible from web application. You have to create windows services for printing. For the printer it doesn't matter that printer is installed on which port it can be on USB or COM port. If you want to print webpage then simply press Ctrl + P then you get print dialog or you can page.print() javascript method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Just a question, a windows service, can be trigger from a web page? or throw the network? Because I need that my server app calls the method to print the ticket, but maybe the printer could be in another computer. So, it that possible?

Comment: ya, web app can trigger a printer. using silverlight control.